# cs-cart: Add multiple quantity text boxes to product options

Tags: cs-cart

I'm wondering how this cs-cart site (http://www.embroideredpoloshirts.eu/embroidered-polo-shirt-uc101-uneek-classic-polo.html) has multiple qty boxes for the different sizes/colours?

By default, cs-cart gives you the option of a combo or radio buttons when using product options. There is only ever one qty box.

I have a similar (but simpler) requirement in that I need the 'size' listed in a table, with a qty box beside each one...

I have set up a simple Product Option (Size) with some variants (Small, Med, Large, etc)...

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to look at [this mod](http://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/22141-qty-matrix-mod-allow-bulk-ordering-of-product-options/).